# How to make image appear when sharing a link/webpage on Twitter?

Tags: html, twitter, metadata, share, meta-tags

I am using a CNN article page as an example:

http://money.cnn.com/2015/01/14/technology/innovationnation/inside-tracker-blood-test/index.html

In the webpage html head there is this tag:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/dam/assets/150114084151-inside-tracker-120x90.png">
```

But when I click on twitter share button to share the page, all i see is:

"The best blood test you'll ever take http://cnnmon.ie/17HrCSL via @CNNMoney"

Even if I log into twitter and shared the page, I still don't see that image! What is wrong? I am trying to do this for my website.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're describing is known as "Twitter Cards". A number of conditions must be fulfilled for it to work on a site; in particular, **the site must be manually approved by Twitter staff**. It will not work on sites that have not been approved.

For more information on Twitter Cards, please refer to:

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started

Comment: I got approval from twitter already, and I would think CNN, one of the biggest news site in the world, have already gotten approval and yet still not working. In fact, I have never seen a working "twitter card" being shared on any webpage, any website.

Comment: They're definitely out there and working. Examples: https://twitter.com/aukin100/status/555537927426805761 https://twitter.com/thewildbunny/status/555537140151754752 https://twitter.com/hgse/status/555538623798710273

Comment: Be sure to use the correct image size: **twitter cards** expects **160x160** but **og** expects **200x200px**.

Comment: Do you NEED to set the image size? If my original image is 640x480 ... wont it just shrink and crop the image?